Visual Studio run into an unexpected problem, and may affect some project system functions. (Open log file)
I've bumped into such kind of issue and don't know how to solve it.
here is log file:

Recoverable System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the
expected range.    at
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32
errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)    at
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.RunningDocumentTable.UnlockDocument(_VSRDTFLAGS
lockType, UInt32 cookie)    at
Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.ProjectFrameOpenCloseListener.FrameEventsLifetime.<>c__DisplayClass20_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
task)    at
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTask.CompleteOnCurrentThread()
at
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTask1.CompleteOnCurrentThread() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ProjectMultiThreadedService.ExecuteSynchronously[T](Func1
asyncAction)    at
Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.HResult.Invoke(Func`1 action,
IServiceProvider vsShellServiceProvider, IProjectFaultHandlerService
projectFaultHandlerService, UnconfiguredProject project)

===================
I used .Net6, can it be a problem for this?

Without any context this is meaningless.

Please clean your solution,
It might possible , one instane of your application alrady running..
